# ADFS SSO using Windows authentication

Tags: single-sign-on, adfs

I'm quite new to ADFS. I need to set up a SSO for web based application using the credentials with which the user authenticates on Windows.

My ADFS server is on premise.

I'm not able to understand if it's possible and how.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, your application has to have a client-side stack for one of:

- OpenID Connect
- SAML 2.0
- WS Federation

I would suggest the former.

There are some [samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/msal/adfs-msal-web-app-web-api) here. Look under the ADAL / MSAL tabs on the left.